# React transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map slides inside switch transition and get the error "Error: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child."

What I do wrong?

```
Slider.Body = function SliderBody({ data, children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <SwitchTransition mode={"out-in"}>
      <TransitionGroup>
        {data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <CSSTransition classNames="fade" key={item.image}>
              {item.toString()}
            </CSSTransition>
          );
        })}
      </TransitionGroup>
    </SwitchTransition>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the data you are mapping inside a div. So it should look something like this -

```
Slider.Body = function SliderBody({ data, children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <SwitchTransition mode={"out-in"}>
      <TransitionGroup>
        <div>
        {data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <CSSTransition classNames="fade" key={item.image}>
              {item.toString()}
            </CSSTransition>
          );
        })}
        </div>
      </TransitionGroup>
    </SwitchTransition>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't have multiple items in the `<TransitionGroup>` component so the solution would be to wrap the map function in an `HTML element`.

You could use `<React.Fragment>` and wrap your map function in it as well.

Let's look at the example using `<React.Fragment>`:

```
Slider.Body = function SliderBody({ data, children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <SwitchTransition mode={"out-in"}>
      <TransitionGroup>
        <React.Fragment>
        {data.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <CSSTransition classNames="fade" key={i}>
              {item.toString()}
            </CSSTransition>
          );
        })}
        </React.Fragment>
      </TransitionGroup>
    </SwitchTransition>
  );
};
```

You can find more about Fragments [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Comment: but now my slider instead slide do nothing :c

Comment: Could you make a sandbox and isolate a problem? Can't help you by heart.

Comment: So hard to put my project in sandbox, but i have ps https://prnt.sc/vowp6m :3
and https://prnt.sc/vowq21

Comment: It is just ignore my slider container and add secons that is have transition group classes

Comment: Try to add key="transition-group-content" inside transition group like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44237033/error-react-children-only-expected-to-receive-a-single-react-element-child).

Comment: It really help me, second container is not adding now, but i still have problem. Now on exit slides dont add same classes :0 https://prnt.sc/vox3cz

Comment: @ВладиславЗабаштевич, can't help you with debugging. If the initial problem that you posted is solved, please mark the correct answer.